# SharePoint Permissions - User Restricted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions, restricted-access

Is there anyway to restrict users to view data only available to their login? I'm trying to create bulk forms with data points for individual logins. But do we have any option to restrict data to be viewed by user available exclusively for their login?

For example, I have a bulk list with entries like Login, Manager login, Skill and some data points. I need to restrict data to be viewed by user who is trying to access it so that particular user can view only his data.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement some logic to set item level permissions based on the field containing the users login.

Some ways to do this:

1. Have a (2010) workflow that runs whenever an item is created or changed that updates the permissions.
2. Impersonate the users so they are the creators of the individual items, and then in advanced list settings set it so users can only read items created by themselves. (Depending on how the data is written to the list, this could be done with PowerShell)
3. Have a scheduled task running to update all items

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to display sharepoint list based on logged in user?

Modify view, in the filter section, select the "Show items only when the following is ture:" and choose "Created by" is equal to "Me":

[image]